# Simple `to_tsvector` configuration - postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How can I change the `to_tsvector` configuration to use a simple tokenization rule like:

- lowercase
- split by spaces only

Executing the following query:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'birthday=19770531 Name=John-Oliver Age=44 Code=AAA-345')
```

I get these lexemes:

```
'-345':9 '19770531':2 '44':6 'aaa':8 'age':5 'birthday':1 'code':7 'john':4 'name':3
```

The kind of searching I'm looking for is like:

```
(!birthday | birthday=19770531) & (code=AAA-345)
```

It means, get me all records that has a text "birthday=19770531" or doesn't have "birthday" at all, and a text equals to "code=AAA-345"). The way lexemes are being created it is not possible. I was expecting to have something like this:

```
'birthday=19770531':1 'age=44':2 'code=aaa-345':4 'name=john-oliver':3
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to code a custom parser.  This can only be done in C.

But you might be able to use the existing testing parser `test_parser`, it seems to do what you want. If not, it would at least be a good starting point.

The problem may be that this is in src/test/modules/, and I don't think it ships with most installation packaging.  So it might take some effort to get it to install.  It would depend on your OS, version, and package manager.